# how to interpolate in javascript without es6

Tags: javascript, interpolation

Im trying to find a way to interpolate an id into a html input tag using javascript without es6.
I've attempted to use concatenation but due to the location of the two interpolations, it is proving difficult.

below is it with es6 (which works fine), however i need it without es6 for certain reasons.

```html
var id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000);
`<input type="text" placeholder="Add a new member" id="search_name_${id}" data_id= "${id}" class="form-control add-member-on-policy-search"/>`,
```

Thanks

Comment: Just build the string with ordinary concatenation operations (`+`).

Comment: [try babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=G4QwTgBAlgJhC8ECyIAuALAdAMwDYHt8wAKFDTMEAOxnwFtiBKCAKggEYAGbnzxgbgBQAY3xUAzqggAjfDACeCCAAMAPFCoAHAK5TU8zQFN4AIlSGAHqhMRNuEMMPp8uGIbCmAgjDggIVQwB3CDpDOml3G1hTcUNwYXQAfSoQUMSAEgBvWABfGxg0EEToiBMs3Jthe3FxU2wiOgBaUSpUMBcIEB9G0PD3RrFGzRcoYXlG2Pj0EwB6AD5lIQhllaA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&timeTravel=true&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.9.0&externalPlugins=)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has no native string interpolation features before ES6.

You could find or write a library function that could do it (e.g. [this sprintf implementation](http://www.diveintojavascript.com/projects/javascript-sprintf)) … but they'd end up using concatenation under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Use a variable to store the id and use that variable in the input tag.

For example:

```
var search_id = "search_name_" + id;
<input type="text" placeholder="Add a new member" id=search_id data_id=id class="form-control add-member-on-policy-search"/>
```